# std::replace gives error

Tags: c++, string, replace, str-replace

I am trying to convert a file path which just have one slash to double slash as shown on the code below.
but it gives me the error shown at the end

```
    #include<algorithm>

    std::string file_path;
    using std::replace;
     while(fgets(fname_buffer,1024,flist))
   {
    token = strtok( fname_buffer," ,\t");
    file_size=atol(token);

    token = strtok(NULL, " ,\t"); 
   strncpy((char*)file_fp,token,32);
   file_fp[32]='\0';

    token = strtok(NULL, "\n");
    file_path=token;
    replace(file_path.begin(),file_path.end(),'\\',"\\\\");
    //file_path.replace(file_path.begin(),file_path.end(),'\\','\\\\');
```

> error C2664: 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::replace(unsigned int,unsigned int,const _Elem *,unsigned int)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::_String_iterator<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>' to 'unsigned int'

Comment: Use [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/replace_all.html).  It's much better than the search-replace-repeat algorithms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`replace` cannot replace one character `'\\'` with two characters `"\\\\"`. The signature of the template method requires `const T&` for the last two parameters, but you are passing a string instead of a character.

Here is how you can do what you need:

```
int p = 0;
while ((p = file_path.find('\\', p)) != string::npos) {
    file_path.insert(p, "\\");
    p += 2;
}
```

Comment: That should be `file_path.insert(p, "\\\\");`

Comment: @AgnelKurian no, not really: the other slash is already there.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to replace a char-type with a string - replace requires the types to be the same:
 **const T&** which in both cases this should be `char`.

```
template < class ForwardIterator, class T >
  void replace ( ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last,
                 const T& old_value, const T& new_value );
```

Here is a code snippet you may find helpful:
(It works by repeated calls to `std::string::replace()` until end-of-string)

```
std::string& sReplaceAll(std::string& sS, 
                         const std::string& sWhat, 
                         const std::string& sReplacement)
{
    size_t pos = 0, fpos;
    while ((fpos = sS.find(sWhat, pos)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        sS.replace(fpos, sWhat.size(), sReplacement);
        pos = fpos + sReplacement.size();
    }
    return sS;
}
```

In your case you would use it like this:

`sReplaceAll(file_path, "\\", "\\\\");`

Comment: It's good pratice to suggest the solution too, here replacing `'\\'` by `"\\"` will make the code work.

Comment: @MatthieuM: it didn't work that way(It gave run time error). The other way round worked but it replaced all the characters in the path with '\'

Comment: I don't think that will work as a `char*` cannot be assigned to a `char`, which is the element of a `std::string`.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I do not think that replacing `'\\'` by `"\\"` is viable, because `std::string` is a container of characters, not strings. In other words, `T` in the template needs to bind to a single character, not to a string (your suggestion would work on a vector of strings, though it would do a different thing).

Comment: @hmjd: exact, sorry I thought this was regex replacement and not the algorithm. John: right, you're doomed to fail here with this algorithm.

Comment: I have tried that. I got **'void std::replace(_FwdIt,_FwdIt,const _Ty &,const _Ty &)' : template parameter '_Ty' is ambiguous**

Comment: Clearly this does not work.  You should test your code before posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

`copy`, `replace`, `transform` and some other algorithms can't create more elements than exist in their input range. (off the top of my head I can't think of any standard algorithms that do allow this)

You can use `regex_replace` to do this:

```
file_path = std::regex_replace(file_path,std::regex("\\"),"\\\\");
```

Comment: compiler says regex_replace is not member of std

Comment: `#include <regex>`. If you're using a version of VS earlier than VS2010 you'll have to use the `std::tr1` version.